# int * vs char * initialization

Tags: c

Take a look at the following C code.

`char * str1 = "hello";`

It creates a char array allocated to read only memory, and str1 is assigning as a pointer to the first element. Being read only, the memory cannot be changed without a segmentation fault. In this statement:

`int * p = 1;`

`p` is now allocated as 1, and can in fact be reassigned to a different value without a segmentation fault occurring. Why is this? Is it just a compiler decision to make the memory read only in the case of string literals?

Comment: "p is now allocated as 1" Nope, p points to address 1, which is likely invalid.

Comment: That's not the case, try it yourself. You can even print the address that p points to. I would say the same thing, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Nwah are you sure? http://cpp.sh/3rob

Comment: @Nwah you have several fundamental misunderstandings here. `str1` *can* be changed to point elsewhere, but the static string itself cannot be modified... and it's not really "allocated". `p` is *not* allocated as 1...  just ends up pointing somewhere (it's also an incompatible conversion btw... you should cast properly), which may or may not be valid (probably not... deref it will probably produce nasal demons on most platforms), and may or may not be modifiable depending on where.

Comment: If you tried printing the value of `&p`, that's the address of `p` itself and not the address `p` points at.

Comment: @Nwah, take a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

Comment: `int * p = 1; => segfault` (on first reference of `p`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ,in `protected mode`, in fact

Comment: Allocated is the wrong word, I by no means think this is good code. If you create a variable int * p = 1, you can then reassign the value with p = 2, and this is not changing the address, the actual value (or as I seem to understand, creating a new int and changing the pointer). *p = 2 does not work, because it is trying to change the actual variable p points to. Try it for yourself.

Comment: int *p = 3333; imagine here you say p now points at address 3333. After if you do *p = 9; later this means you say please go on address 3333 and write there number 9. But address 3333 must be valid otherwise you are writing to a territory "which doesn't belong to you"

Comment: I see where the confusion is arising now. int * p does in fact assign an address. I did not think this was otherwise till I ran into the problem. Where it was confusing was p = 2 after that, it appears doing this actually assigns a memory reference and gives it the value 2. This is why, as you say *p = 9 would not work. The pointer value after the int * p = 1 assignment is 0000000001, and after p = 2 - 0000000023FE40. Is this p = 2 compiler magic?

Comment: I'd also like to add that the char * str1 = "hello" can also be reassigned in the same way with str1 = "hello2". So the compiler just considers the assignment of a value to a pointer as a reassignment of that pointer to a newly placed value?

Comment: You should always assign valid memory address to pointer. Just assigning random number is a bad idea. Its like telling someone random address of yours- surely he wont find you when he/she comes to that address

Comment: Yes, I agree. But that doesn't answer why the previous statements happen.

Comment: 1) The string literal **can** be in unmodifyable memory, but there is no requirement from the standard. 2) writing to a string literal or a `const` quaslified variable invokes undefined behaviour. There is no requirement for segfault. Using a pointer which is not `const` qualified is legal, but often a sign of bad programming style (it is illegal in C++, fyi).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `int * p = 1;`
>
> `p` is now allocated as 1.

**Wrong. `p` is now pointing to memory address 1.**

This can lead to various problems, starting with the fact that you have not properly allocated any memory block starting at that address.

To make things worse, even if you've somehow managed to allocate a memory block at address 1, since this address is not aligned to `int` (i.e., 1 is not divisible by `sizeof int`), your code is prone to unaligned load/store operations.

If your platform (i.e., designated compiler + underlying HW architecture) does not support these operations, then any attempt to read or write via `p` could lead to:

- A bus (aka segmentation) fault in the good scenario
- An undetermined outcome in the bad scenario

The former is better than the latter, because with a bus fault, at least you immediately become aware of the problem, whereas with an undetermined outcome, some unexpected behavior might emerge at some later point during the execution of your program, leaving you to the mercy of the god of debug sessions.

Comment: Indeed, I assumed the value was being assigned properly. Why is it that p = 2 actually assigns p to the value 2 and the memory address 000000000023FE40? Is it because the compiler considers this as creating a new int and assigning its address to p? Keep in mind im doing a printf("%p", &p), which seems strange.

Comment: @Nwah: I think you're mixing between the value of `p` and the address of `p` (i.e. the value of `&p`). if `p` is static and/or global, then the memory address of `p`  is determined by the compiler. Otherwise (if it is non-static local), then the memory address of `p` may be different every time the function is invoked. Please note that none of this (including what I've mentioned about unaligned load/store operations) is dictated by the C language standard, i.e., it is subjected to compiler implementation.

Comment: @Nwah: Also, please note that you can only accept one answer as the correct one (I've noticed you accepted mine after accepting the other one)... So choose the one you think answers your question best.

Comment: printf("%d %p", p, &p) prints 2 and 000000000023FE40. &p always has this address at every execution. Does this fit into the first case? Bear in mind the program is only 3 lines of variable assignment in main.

Comment: @Nwah: "the memory address of `p` **may** be different every time the function is invoked".

Answer (score 8):

There are many things you misunderstand it seems.

First here:

```
char * str1 = "hello";
```

Nobody restricts you to do

```
str1 = "hello again";
```

at later point. And it will still be correct. What you can't do is however:

```
str1[0] = 'a'; // This you can't do- because you aren't allowed to modify string literal
```

So it means you should not change the string literal, but you can make the pointer point to a different object.

With the integer example:

```
int * p = 1;
```

Above line isn't good because `p` points now to memory address 1 and dereferencing it is a bad idea.

Functionally, `char` or `int` pointers behave mostly the same, just you can't modify a string literal, that is the only restriction.

In case of both `char` and `int` pointers you can reassign the pointer.

And (excluding the case when char pointer points to string literal) you can also change the contents of the object to which they point. e.g.

```
int x = 1;
int *y = &x;
*y = 19; // Fine, now x has value 19

char a = 'b';
char *c = &a;
*c = 'r'; // Fine, now a has value 'r'
```

---

To sum up I would say it like this: `char` and `int` pointers and all pointers in general "behave" the same way: you can assign addresses to them and also change objects to which they point (granted they point to valid memory), just in case of string literals, if `char` pointer happens to point to a string literal you aren't allowed to change *the* *object* to which the `char` pointer points to.

Comment: **int *p = avalue;** is often used in embedded programming where there are memory mapped devices.

Comment: I just reread that and realized you said int * p assigns an address, guess we're back to square 1?

Comment: @cup ok could be just in general doesn't seem good idea to assign some memory address to pointer directly

Comment: @Nwah Please have a look once again, updated answer with some details

Comment: So the difference is reassignment vs changing the actual memory? You still state that int * p = 1 assigns an address when it assigns an actual variable.

Comment: @Nwah No  int * p = 1 means make p point to address 1. Getting object from address 1 is a different thing and happens using dereferencing. But you should only dereference pointers pointing to valid memory. Basically int and char pointers have same behavior, with restriction you can't change to what char pointer points to if it is a string literal.

Comment: ` int main(){
    int * p = 1;
    int * s = "pp";

    printf("%d\n", p);

    p = 2;
    
    printf("%s %d\n", s, p);
    printf("%p\n", &p);
}` Outputs 1, pp, 2, 000000000023FE40                                                                   Doesn't this clearly show that *p is actually an assignment?

Comment: @Nwah Please try to read pointers once again on some resource, just keep in mind char and int pointers - and all pointers - have same behavior, can point somewhere and can change objects to which they points. Just the restriction is you can't change string literal if char pointer points to it.

Comment: In this code, you could just replace `int *p` with `int p` and it would be the exact same program. You're using the int-ptr as if it were an int. It isn't. It's a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

nice question, first compare these:

```
char* str1 = "hello";
const char* const str1 = "hello";
char str1[] = "hello";
```

in `char* str1 = "hello";` str1 is a pointer to a char type. You can do pointer arithmetic, `str1++` will compile, this puts data in read-only parts of the memory (const data). and using str1[0]='a'; will result to runtime error(but compile ok).
in `const char* const str1 = "hello";` data and pointer are const: using `str1[0]='a';` will result to compile error.
in `char str1[] = "hello";` str1  is an array (const pointer). using `str1[0]='a';` is ok, but using `str1++` will result to compile error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char *p){
    char c;
    char* q = p;
    while (*q) q++; 
    q--; // point to the end
    while (p < q) {
        c = *p;
        *p++ = *q;
        *q-- = c;
    }
}

int main(){
    char s[]  = "DCBA";
    reverse( s);
    printf("%s\n", s); // ABCD
}
```

and second:
nice thing about pointer is: **pointer is a variable too**, like 'int' with one difference:
using `i++` with int just adds one to `i`, but `p++` with pointer adds one memory size of underlying type e.g. `int32_t* p;` p++ adds 4 (int32_t size) to p value.
`p++` increments p variable memory itself, not memory it may points.(this is answer you are looking for).

now compare these:

```
int ary[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
//int* p2 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int* p = ary;
const int* const q = ary;
```

in this sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int ary[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    //int* p2 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int* p = ary;
    const int* const q = ary;

    ary[0] = 10; // ok
    p[0] = 100; // ok
    //q[0] = 11; // error
    printf("%x\n", p);
    printf("%d\n", p[0]); // 100
    return 0;
}
```

while `char* str1 = "hello";` is valid, but `int* p2 = { 1, 2, 3 };` is not valid. also `char* p2 = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 };` is not valid. so `char* str1 = "hello";` is special compiler trick in compile time, which puts "hello" in readonly memory space.
i hope this helps.